# Trying to call MATLAB scripts from Python

Tags: python, matlab, system-integration

I'm trying to integrate Python and MATLAB, I wanna call my .m script from my python environment.

I read the documentation and understood that this could be done like this:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.MyScript(nargout=0)
```

I've shared a session from matlab with: `matlab.engine.shareEngine` before trying these commands in python.

I can't seem to get it to work for some reason, I don't get any output in my python environment, all I get is a sound that sounds like matlab's error sound.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, what do you think should happen? What does `MyScript` do?

Comment: let's assume MyScript is: `x=1; disp(x);` , then I should see '1' printed out, at the moment I'm seeing nothing and have no access to any variables from the matlab workspace (tried to access using the `eng.workspace['x']`)

Comment: Are you sure you are in the right directory? Does `import os; os.listdir()` list `MyScript.m` ?

Comment: Yes, I have myScript.m in the same directory as my .py file